# Ubuntu Server DDoS protection

Tags: ubuntu, security, firewall, ddos, csf

I've seen many articles on DDoS protection, but none work. I need protection for a socket server i'm running on the server. It's running on port 9876 and it's for a flash-based game. when it gets attacked, the whole dedicated server goes offline for a few minutes. I have CSF firewall installed, and I tried configuring the portflood settings, but nothing helped.

my question is: how can I stop or slow down attacks on port 9876, it is NOT a webserver. it is a socket server written in PHP. I also have another one running on 9875 that is in python, but either way, how can I stop or slow down attacks??

Comment: Does it have to be open? Can you put it behind a proxy of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misusing the term "DDoS". If this was happening, there's *nothing* you can do about it other notifying your upstream provider.

If the game's being overwhelmed by requests, you can try to rate-limit the requests to something the server can handle. See this for details: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187

If that doesn't help, then there may simply be too much traffic.